# Error in Google Play "com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException:" in React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, crash, google-play

I have already published a React Native app in google play, and it gives me this strange Error at Google Play console at Crashes. I have already searched for something similar, but i have already struggled. Any help appreciated.

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:888)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:213)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:929)
```

Comment: I got the same issue but cannot find a solution

Comment: @AIK hmm.. I am searching to add something like crashlytics or anything similar, to track crashes in more human readable way. I dont know if we can use debug symbols .. If i will find something, i will update here.